# Rails enum mapping to displayable text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

The Rails 4 enum implementation is rather nice for making a status field such as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:goodstanding, :outstanding]
```

But if I want to display text depending on the status, this text mapping should be in one place and the enum doesn't offer a solution to map to text.

Here is what I had before

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {
    :outstanding => "Outstanding balance",
    :goodstanding => "In good standing"
  }
```

Which allowed me to do

```
User::STATUS[user.status] # "In good standing"
```

to display my text. Any suggestions on how to do this with the newer enum type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done in rails 4.1+, but it behaves unexpectedly, and has been fixed in rails 5 branch.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16459

For example:

```
class User
  enum name: {
    foo: 'myfoo',
    bar: 'mybar'
  }
end
```

Now when you do:

```
u = User.new(name: 'foo')
u.save
```

Then it will execute:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('myfoo', '2015-07-20 04:53:16', '2015-07-20 04:53:16')
```

For `foo` it inserted `myfoo`. Now when you do:

```
u = User.last

u.name
 => "foo"

u[:name]
 => "myfoo"
```

I have tried the above. Whlie there are various gems available too, I have never used them but may be they help you:

1. [enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)
2. [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum)
3. [classy_enum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum)

Source: [Possibility of mapping enum values to string type instead of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105813/possibility-of-mapping-enum-values-to-string-type-instead-of-integer)

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for fixed in Rails 5. I saw this answer elsewhere, and have seen a couple of these gems (not enumerize). I just didn't want to use a gem for this. Looking forward to it in Rails 5, thanks.

Comment: Can someone update this with a better example like the question?  as a newbie, this example is very confusing.