# Giving multiple attributes per enum value in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, ruby-on-rails-6.1

The problem: There is a list of `enum` values, say `status`. But every status needs more information per key than just `passed` or `failed`.

I'm looking for a more graceful solution to what I have now:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: {passed: 0, failed: 1}, _default: :passed

  def icon
    Result.icons[status]
  end

  def text
    Result.texts[status]
  end

  def self.icons
    {passed: 'fa-check', failed: 'fa-cross'}.with_indifferent_access
  end

  def self.texts
    {passed: 'Your result has passed', failed: 'Your result has failed'}.with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```

So in the view I can do something like:

```
result = Result.new(status: :passed)
result.icon
result.text
```

I found a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718196/782713) with a seemingly graceful solution with `ActiveModel::Serializer`, but it's not a working example. At least, I didn't get it to work in Rails 6.

My solution works *okay*, but when you start getting 5 attributes per status with 8 different statuses, it's getting quite tedious.

Maybe I should actually map it to a yaml file? Or use `i18n`?

Anyway, hope my question is clear, looking forward seeing your solutions to this.